# Alternatives to reversing polarity on a DC to DC step up converter?

Tags: relay, dc-dc-converter, dc-motor, reverse-polarity

I am looking to drive a 12V DC motor with an encoder attached ([Motor Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08BL9D6BH)). The battery I am using is 6V ([Battery Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00K8V2RW0)) which requires me to use a DC-to-DC step-up converter ([Converter Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B019GY2DC8)). To reverse the polarity of the motor, I am using a relay ([Relay Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0876D9KLD)). I quickly learned that the converter cannot handle reverse polarity. How can I reverse polarity and step up voltage?

Comment: Is there an additional complication to this requirement?  As in the first answer, is reversing just the output converter lines a problem?

Comment: @Nedd I was of the presumption that the whole circuit reverses polarity. From now on, should I assume electronic components such as converters, isolate (for lack of a more technical word) circuits in certain aspects such as polarity? Are diodes in the converter the reason for the isolating behavior?

Comment: Active electronics trpically responds differenly to reversed polarity.  diodes will be part of it.

Comment: A DC/DC converter is a complex system, utilizing transistors, diodes, capacitors, and other components that are polarity sensitive, it must be powered only from a power source of the specified polarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just connect the relay between the DC-DC converter and the motor.

Comment: Could you elaborate, maybe post a schematic?